# How to have JavaScript functions work across different HTML pages?

Tags: javascript, html

I am building a website with several HTML pages, and going to fill up info on different pages through an API. I have added onclick listeners to HTML elements like this:

```
// ASSIGNING ELEMENTS AS VARIABLES

const EPL = document.getElementById('epl'); 
const bundesliga = document.getElementById('bundesliga'); 
const laliga = document.getElementById('laliga');

// ONCLICKS 
EPL.onclick = function() { 
getStandings('2021'); 
location.replace('standings.html');
 } 

bundesliga.onclick = function() { 
getStandings('2088'); 
location.replace('standings.html'); 
}

 laliga.onclick = function() {
 getStandings('2224'); 
location.replace('standings.html'); 
}
```

When one of these is clicked, I call a function (getStandings) with its unique argument to fetch some data from the API. I also want to move to another HTML page, for which I used location.replace.

I'm caught in a dilemma: if I use the same JS file for every HTML page, when I get to the new HTML page, I get errors as the new HTML page does not have every element:

```
main.js:41 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null
```

But if I use different JS files, maybe one JS file for each HTML file, I cannot carry forward the bits of information I need. How can I get to the new HTML page, with its own JS file, without stopping and losing everything in the function I'm in currently, under the JS file of the old page? For example, the argument '2021' or '2088' are to be passed into the getStandings() function which will populate the new HTML page with data from an API. If I jump to a new HTML page with a new JS file, this is lost.

Is there a better way to organise my files?

Comment: I would use URL variables, like `standings.html?id=2224`.

Comment: This worked best in the end. I didn't even know that was a thing, but I pulled up some documentations and it was fairly simple and effective. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can set your event listeners on the condition that the elements are not null e.g.

```
const EPL = document.getElementById('epl'); 
const bundesliga = document.getElementById('bundesliga'); 
const laliga = document.getElementById('laliga');

if(EPL){
    EPL.onclick = function() { 
        getStandings('2021'); 
        location.replace('standings.html');
    } 
}

etc...
```

Comment: Thanks, I believe this should work, but is there a better way that allows for "transferring of data" from one js file to another when I jump from one HTML file to another? Otherwise for bigger projects I'd be restricted to lumping every function of every HTML page into one JS file.

Comment: You could wrap the above in an export function statement (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export) and import it into wherever it's needed (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import).

Comment: I see I can export functions to other files, but how do I export information that is dependent on which element is clicked?

Answer (score 0):

Solved! As [amn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/254343/amn) said, I can add [URL parameters](https://www.sitepoint.com/get-url-parameters-with-javascript/) to the end of the URL of the new HTML page, then get the variables from its own URL once I'm on the new HTML page.

Answer (score -1):

I think I would rather use classes instead of IDs to define the listener, and maybe IDs for dedicated action.